# Use transform details of object in maxscript upon selection

Tags: maxscript

I want to use the position value of the object I select in max script.  I understand it is easily possible via '$.pos.X' and few more methods. But the only limitation is that I have to click a button to run that script or have to link it to some function.

I am looking to use the details real time, as soon as I select any object it should display the properties in a text box. Any help on this would be highly appreciated. Many thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

There's a topic in the maxscript reference about callbacks, that's what you want. As an example:

```
fn fn_handleSelectionChanged evnt handle = 
(
    if selection.count == 1 do
    (
        local obj = selection[1]
        format "%.pos.x: %\n" obj.name obj.pos.x
    )
)

::callbackItem = NodeEventCallback mouseUp:on delay:1000 selectionChanged:fn_handleSelectionChanged
```

Comment: Thanks for reply.. I read the maxscript reference file and your example. I am stuck at one place. Please check this link [link](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1387m0BqH_Q4FtemsBBuq3-HpWm2ACgMn1D1zRX6mqig/edit?usp=sharing) I am able to run print function directly in callback but not able to call a defined function..

Comment: When you are referencing the function like this, it has to be visible from the global scope. In your case, one way to do that is use `"scale1.fn_handleSelectionChanged()"` instead.